# Initialise all pages/components at start

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic3

I am building an Ionic 2 App. I have 4 tabs. I want to initialise all or some-specific pages/components at the start of App.

[image: Dashboard]

Right now its like that only `Dashboard.ts` is initialised, but other 3 tabs' pages are not initialised. So when I click on `CcExpire` or `Customers` tabs only then they are initialised.

By initialise I mean calling the constructor of the page/component because I have to update the flags (as shown above the tabs). And these flags are dependent on the logic written in their respective pages.

Lets take CcExpire page as an example. In the `constructor` I am subscribing to the event (triggered by other pages) which then trigger another event to update the tabs. I think I can also duplicate this code to somewhere else but it would not be a good idea. Below is the code for

**CcExpire.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import { Customer } from '../../models/customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'ccexpire.html'
})

export class CcExpirePage {

  public customersCcExpired: Customer[] = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public events: Events, public storage: Storage) {

    this.events.subscribe('customerListUpdated', () => {
      this.updateLists();
      console.log("CcExpirePage");
    });

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.updateLists();

  }

  updateLists() {
    this.storage.get('customers').then((val) => {

      this.customersCcExpired = [];

      if (val) {

        val.forEach(customer => {

          if (customer.methodOfPayment == "Debit/ Credit Card" && !customer.cardRenewed) {

            // Populate each customers' list w.r.t. respective payment due dates
            var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds 

            const [month, year] = customer.ccExpire.split('/');

            // var dummyDate = new Date("1/" + customer.ccExpire);
            var ccExpireDateLastDay = new Date(year, month, 0);

            var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((ccExpireDateLastDay.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / (oneDay)));

            if (diffDays < 30 && diffDays > -1) {
              this.customersCcExpired.push(customer);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      this.storage.set("ccExpireEventCount", this.customersCcExpired.length).then(() => {

        this.events.publish("updateTabs");
      });

    });
  }

  showConfirm(selectedCustomer: Customer) {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Renew',
      message: 'Has customer renewed the credit card?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'No',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Disagree clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Renewed',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Agree clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }
}
```

I believe that there should be some configurations that I am missing. Let me know if I can initialise my component(s) at the start of App.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { CcExpirePage } from '../pages/ccexpire/ccexpire';
import { CustomersPage } from '../pages/customers/customers';
import { DashboardPage } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import { SettingPage } from '../pages/setting/setting';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AddCustomerPage } from '../pages/addcustomer/addcustomer';

import { CustomerService } from '../services/customer.service'

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': '54074253'
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    CcExpirePage,
    CustomersPage,
    DashboardPage,
    SettingPage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage,
    AddCustomerPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    CcExpirePage,
    CustomersPage,
    DashboardPage,
    SettingPage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage,
    AddCustomerPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    CustomerService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Auth } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

import { CcExpirePage } from '../pages/ccexpire/ccexpire';
import { CustomersPage } from '../pages/customers/customers';
import { DashboardPage } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import { SettingPage } from '../pages/setting/setting';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { AddCustomerPage } from '../pages/addcustomer/addcustomer';

import LoaderUtil from '../utils/loader.util';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public auth: Auth,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      // Initialize util classes
      LoaderUtil.init(this.loadingCtrl);

      // TODO: Initialize tab values onload

      this.rootPage = CcExpirePage;

      if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        this.rootPage = TabsPage;
      } else {
        this.rootPage = LoginPage;
      }

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using lazy loading?

Comment: @suraj I am not sure about it. How can I know that am I using lazy loading, is there any configuration for it ?

Comment: is it ionic 2 or ionic 3? which version?

Comment: no.. in your package.json.. what is the version of `ionic-angular`? also do you have individual modules for each page?

Comment: In package.json I have : ionic-angular -> 3.1.0. Also I have updated my question. For each page I have a `ts`, `html` and `scss` files. And all pages has `@Component` in it.

Comment: @suraj if you want to look into the code, then it is uploaded at https://github.com/junaidbinsarfraz/Reminder-App .

Comment: y not do this logic in a singleton provider instead? then both dashboard and page can retrieve data from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143643/discussion-between-junaid-and-suraj).

Comment: you will have to use a service to update the tabs or use ngrx . the behaviour you are facing is the default behaviour of angular apps